# How to create UI block in Xamarin.Forms same as position: fixed in HTML?

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, position, fixed

Here's my attempt using Grid and ScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="MobApp.TestPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Text="News Header" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />

    <ScrollView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout x:Name="NewsItems">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 1 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 1 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 2 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 2 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 3 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 3 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 4 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 4 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 5 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 5 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 6 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 6 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="News 7 Title" />
                <Label Text="News 7 Text" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

But when scrolling on Android 4.4 (API 19) Emulator ScrollView content overlaps Label "News Header". In addition in manuals strongly recommends not use nested ScrollView.

How can I solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fascinating phenomenon that took me a couple of days of life) The task truly is solved through the Grid + ScrollView, everything works fine from my example. Apparently I had something wrong with the emulators. It all started with how I noticed that the emulator (Nougat 7.1) provided by default after installing Xamarin, displays the scroll as needed. I understood and began to dig. All the emulators that I created (with any api from 4.4 to 7.0) - displayed a scroll with the bug above. To change / copy or recreate the same emulator as provided by default did not work, the emulator manager cursed some kind of error. I digged even deeper, it took a lot of time and nerves, but the result paid off:

1. Updated Android SDK to 26 (latest) version
2. Updated Xamarin Android Emulator Manager to the latest version
3. Enabled the hardware virtualization technology in BIOS
4. Through the SDK package manager for Android, installed HAXM. But in fact, it is not installed, but simply downloaded, you need after that to additionally find it on your computer (I have it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager) and run intelhaxm-android.exe
5. Happy end. After that, the emulators I created show all the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just a case of the first `Grid` `RowDefinition` `Height` needs to be increased slightly or set to `auto` (if you don't mind the cyclic calculation hit )

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And yes do not use nested `scrollview` it dosn't make sense and will likely behave irrationally

**Update**

Maybe try changing the [`VerticalOptions`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.View.VerticalOptions/) in the scrollview or  `<Label Text="News Header"`

[LayoutOptions](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions/)

**Update 2**

Also try removing the column on the grid and column specifiers on your controls, i have had weird layout issues before regarding columns

Also try and replace your stack layouts with a grid.

> Note : I know these suggestions are hit and miss however sometimes you
>   just need to tweak things until they work unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it doesn't work. I set Height="90" and it still [look like](http://shot.qip.ru/00UU0v-695nqPrPp/) News Header doesn't exist on the page.

Comment: @Lev a few more things to try

Comment: Tried all that you advised - ineffectually( I even tried to put scrollview into AbsoluteLayot - no changes.

Comment: @lev you need to try a minimal solution, as this should work scrollview should work fine in a grid. However I appreciate xamarin can be a bit fickle. Try put it all in a stack view instead of a grid. Maybe you can also put an image of what's happening in your post as it may help other people understand

Comment: I already tried a dozen combinations, including just this:

    <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="NEWS TITLE" HeightRequest="40" />
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,100,100" Margin="0,60">
                    <StackLayout x:Name="NewsItems" />
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

And filling "NewsItems" from C#. But, by the way, ListView does not cause such a problem.

Comment: [here is the image of what happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4sWn.png)